# Turning a statically linked library into a dynamic one

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I know this question has been asked a few times, but none of the solutions have worked for me.  I have a statically linked library that I would like to use with a JNI layer with versions pre Java 8.  Based on my reading of ["how to link static library into dynamic library in gcc"](/q/2649735), it seems possible.  Here is my command line:

`/usr/bin/g++ -shared -std=c++0x   -D__extern_always_inline=inline -Wall -pedantic -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -Wl,--whole-archive target/vw_jni.a -o target/vw_jni.lib`

This is based on writing a JNI layer to the [Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) library.

At this point in the build process I have statically created a file called `target/vw_jni.a` through static linking

`` target/vw_jni.a: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
target/vw_jni.a: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbeginS.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
target/vw_jni.a: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__libc_csu_init'
target/vw_jni.a:(.text+0x1cea20): first defined here
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_fini':
(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `__libc_csu_fini'
target/vw_jni.a:(.text+0x1ceab0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtendS.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
target/vw_jni.a:(.data+0x2630): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: target/vw_jni.a: .preinit_array section is not allowed in DSO
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

I'm not sure what this means and when I search around for it find results such as ["C program no longer compiles in Ubuntu"](/q/14589022#14589363) that seem to suggest that I forgot a `-o` flag, but I know I have not.

1. Is what I'm trying to do possible?
2. What am I doing wrong?

I'm doing this on a Docker instance obtained through `docker pull ubuntu:14.04`

UPDATE:

I'm able to get rid of a few of the errors with the following command line

`/usr/bin/g++ -shared -std=c++0x   -D__extern_always_inline=inline -Wall -pedantic -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -nostdlib  -Wl,--whole-archive target/vw_jni.a -o target/vw_jni.lib`

This generates the following output

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .note.gnu.build-id section, --build-id ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: target/vw_jni.a: .preinit_array section is not allowed in DSO
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

The reason I think this works is that by excluding the standard lib I don't have the redefinitions.  I'm not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: If nothing else, you can extract all of the members of the library into an empty directory, and link these into a dynamic library (supposing all of the members are .o files, at least).

Comment: I suppose I could.  Ideally I'd like to package this library in the maven artifact so I'd have to package all those in as well.

Comment: Do you know that each object in the static library was compiled with `-fPIC`?

Comment: I know that all the VW code was.  This also includes the following linker options `-l boost_program_options -l pthread -l z`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is with the command line you're using. The flags `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive` apply to all subsequent arguments on the command line, which includes a number of standard libraries and object files (e.g., `-lc`, `crt0.o`, `libc_nonshared.a`, etc.) that are automatically appended behind the scenes.

If there's no `--no-whole-archive` switch directly after the filenames of static libraries you intend to bring in, this will also apply `--whole-archive` to the built-in archives that come after your last argument, e.g., it will try to also bring in every object from `libc.a`, `libm.a`, etc. which will at the very least fail with a "multiple definition" error. Try adding `--no-whole-archive` switch to your command line directly after `target/vw_jni.a` so you end up with something like:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -shared -std=c++0x   -D__extern_always_inline=inline -Wall -pedantic -O3 \
  -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -fPIC \
  -Wl,--whole-archive target/vw_jni.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
  -o target/vw_jni.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *practically* not wise, because if you put the object files extracted from some static library these object files still remain position dependent code.

Shared libraries should very preferably contain [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (because the dynamic linker `ld-linux.so` is `mmap`-ing segments inside the `.so` at some random address, e.g. because of ASLR), otherwise the dynamic linker would have to process a big lot of relocations (so dynamic linking becomes very inefficient).

So even if you succeed to convert your static library into a shared one, it won't be wise to do so.

So keep your static library as is, or recompile their source code with `-fPIC` to build a shared object.

Comment: I'll preface this with the fact that I'm not an expert in g++, but I do have the ability to completely recompile from source.  I was building with -fPIC when compiling.  I think linked the static library with both -static and -fPIC.  If this is not smart, please let me know.

Comment: If you have the source code, just recompile it into a shared object.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  The problem is that I need to include all the dependencies and I can't figure out a way to do that.  Do you know of a way?

Comment: Identify the rule that builds your static library. The dependencies attached to that rule should be sufficient for you to construct suitable dependencies for your dynamic library.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean